# Exclude other cells from counting of references when copy and pasting formulas

Tags: excel

I would just like to ask how can i copy and paste formulas that would have a continuous count. In my case, I have this formula "='PRODUCTIONSTATUS'!B940" located in cell D8, I would like to copy it to cell J8 and wanted to have a formula of "='PRODUCTIONSTATUS'!C940" because when I do the normal copy and pasting, the one that would reflect to cell J8 was  "='PRODUCTIONSTATUS'!H940". I hope somebody can help me. It would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: How many instances you want to copy and paste?? is there any pattern to put the formula in J8 after D8??? Why not E8 to I8???

Comment: Thank for responding  There's a formula in D8, that's the one I intended to copy and paste. There's a 5 cell interval in between from the source cell to the destination cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have data in the sheet `PRODUCTIONSTATUS` from cells `B940` through `E940` (B940, C940, D940, E940 etc..)

Use the below formula in cell `D8`,

`=IFERROR(INDEX(PRODUCTIONSTATUS!$B$940:$E$940,0,IF(MOD(COLUMN(F:F),6)=0,(COLUMN(F:F)/6),999)),"")`

You can copy paste this formula to cell `J8` or just drag the fill handle to the right per your needs. The formula will fill only the cells with 5-cell interval. Let me know in case of any clarification

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @JennyOyao Please upvote and mark my answer as correct if you found this useful. Thanks !!